# pyinstaller EXE opens 2 console windows for a child process

Tags: python, windows, cmd, youtube, windows-console

I made a YouTube video downloader that uses cmd to run youtube-dl in a new console window. When I run the program by itself it works perfectly, but when I freeze it and hit the download button, it opens two console windows and runs the program in only one of them. The other just sits there until the program ends.

Here is my code entirely. Be gentle I'm still very new.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os


class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # -----------Main window--------------------
        self.mainwindow = Frame(parent)
        self.mainwindow.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        # -----------Frames--------------------
        self.topFrame = Frame(self.mainwindow, bg="gray20")
        self.topFrame.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        self.midFrame = Frame(self.mainwindow, bg="gray20")
        self.midFrame.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        self.URLframe = Frame(self.midFrame, bg="gray20")
        self.URLframe.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        self.folderframe = Frame(self.midFrame, bg="gray20")
        self.folderframe.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        self.bottomFrame = Frame(self.mainwindow, bg="gray20")
        self.bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        # -----------Top label--------------------
        self.Toplabel = Label(self.topFrame,
                              text="YouTube Hoarder", font=("Courier", 44),
                              fg="blue2", bg="gray20",
                              height=3, width=50,
                              )
        self.Toplabel.pack()

        # -----------URL entry--------------------
        self.URL_entry = Entry(self.URLframe, width=90)
        self.URL_entry.focus_force()
        self.URL_entry.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=15)

        self.URL_text = Label(self.URLframe,
                              text="Gimme URL",
                              height=1, width=10,
                              bg="light blue"
                              )
        self.URL_text.pack(side=LEFT, pady=6)

        # -----------folder entry--------------------
        self.DirVar = StringVar(self.mainwindow)

        self.folder_entry = Entry(self.folderframe, width=90,
                                  textvariable=self.DirVar)
        self.folder_entry.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=15)

        self.folder_text = Label(self.folderframe,
                                 text="Gimme folder",
                                 height=1, width=10,
                                 bg="light blue"
                                 )
        self.folder_text.pack(side=LEFT, pady=6)

        # -----------buttons--------------------
        self.Download_button = Button(self.bottomFrame,
                                      text="Download",
                                      width=20, height=4,
                                      bg="light green",
                                      command=self.download_process
                                      )
        self.Download_button.pack(side=RIGHT)

        self.find_folder_button = Button(self.midFrame,
                                         text="Folder Directory",
                                         width=12, height=2,
                                         bg="light green",
                                         command=self.print_message2
                                         )
        self.find_folder_button.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5)

        # -----------options menu--------------------
        self.Type_list = ["best", "mp3", "mp4"]
        self.Variable = StringVar(self.mainwindow)
        self.Variable.set(self.Type_list[0])
        self.file_option = OptionMenu(self.bottomFrame, self.Variable,
                                      *self.Type_list)
        self.file_option.pack(side=LEFT)

    def print_message2(self):
        self.dir_opt = options = {}
        options['initialdir'] = 'Downloads'

        self.DirName = filedialog.askdirectory(**self.dir_opt)
        self.DirVar.set(self.DirName)

    def download_process(self):
        self.givenURL = self.URL_entry.get()
        self.givenFT = self.Variable.get()
        os.system('start /wait cmd /c youtube-dl --output '
                  '"{0}\%(title)s.%(ext)s" -i -f '
                  '{1}/best --yes-playlist "{2}"'.format(
                  self.DirName, self.givenFT, self.givenURL))

root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry("{}x{}".format(700 , 400))
root.title("YouTube Hoarder")
root.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\tjhall\Downloads\LT3WE.ico')
myapp = MyApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `os.system` uses `cmd /c`. If your process isn't attached to a console, a new console window (conhost.exe) is created for cmd. You then use `start`, which runs a process attached to a new (second) console.

Comment: I doubt you need the cmd shell or a console window. Try using `import subprocess;` `CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000;` `args = ['youtube-dl', '--output', '{}\%(title)s.%(ext)s'.format(self.DirName), '-i', '-f', '{}/best'.format(self.givenFT), '--yes-playlist', self.givenURL];` `subprocess.call(args, creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)`.

Comment: @ eryksun I adjusted the code as you said any it fixed the problem. Everything is working perfectly now. Thank you. If you submit an answer I will mark it as correct. I have not looked into your other suggestion yet though. I kinda want to keep the console window for now because youtube-dl outputs a lot of useful info to it while it is downloading (%finished, time remaining, output folder, ect.) Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @eryksun I did have one more question. How do you determine the output folder when using "PyInstaller"? I cannot seem to find any documentation on that.